# Listen for newly registered event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm currently working on a project for my university. One thing I need to do there is to synchronize all registered JavaScript event handlers with the server. I.e. I need to know which elements have a particular event handler.

I already use [VisualEvent](https://github.com/DataTables/VisualEvent) to find out which elements have event handlers and it works really great.

But the thing I need is to have an event listener which is called every time an event handler is registered for a DOM element.

So basically every time something like `$("#foo").click(...)` or `$("#foo").bind(...)` is called, I need to get the information that a new event handler has been registered for this element.

Vice versa I need a listener when a event handler is removed from a DOM element, but this is  not mandatory for the first prototype.

Is there a way I can attach a handler globally to all event handler registrations?

If you need any more information, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: why does the server need to know?

Comment: This is part of a research project for remote-controlling a website. So the server needs to know which elements are clickable.

Comment: I'm certain there's a better way to approach the problem, but I don't know enough about the problem to give you any good advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, all methods to attach events go through `jQuery.fn.on`, so it's a simple case of over-riding that function and going wild;

```
(function () {

    var old = jQuery.fn.on;

    jQuery.fn.on = function (events, selector, data, handler) {
        // Ensure you still attach the events
        var result = old.apply(this, arguments); 

        // Now do your own thing

        // Inside here, `this` refers to the jQuery object on which `on` was invoked;
        // it's not a specific element like it normally is within jQuery. You then
        // therefore use something like `this.each(function () { /* this */ }); to 
        // target each element in the set.

        // You might want to normalize the variables, as selector and data are optional,
        // and events can be an object or string
        jQuery.post('/spy.php', {
            events: events,
            selector: selector,
            data: data
        }, jQuery.noop);

        return result; // keep the signature of `on`, and return the value `on()` *would* have done.
    };

}());
```

If you're using jQuery < 1.7 and can't upgrade, you can do something similar to above, but will have to override `bind()`, `live()`, `delegate()` etc.

Comment: Although you'd still need some method to identify the elements where the event was attached. Not sure how that could work unless every element had a unique id in the markup. If that's the case you could use something like `elements: this.map(function(){ return this.id; }).get().join(",")` in the post.